# Symfony 5: 404 page for /lucky/number application

Tags: php, apache, symfony, http-status-code-404

I just started learning Symfony and try create 1th application by article https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

WebServer: Apache 2.4.41

Server: Ubuntu 20

PHP: 7.4.3

1. I created domain on server `symfony`.
2. Installed in /var/www/html/symfony/ by command `symfony new --full ./`
3. Add required files (controller and write route to config/routes.yaml). Installed `composer require symfony/apache-pack`.
4. Execute `$ php bin/console debug:router`:

   | Name | Method | Scheme | Host | Path |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | ... |  |  |  |  |
   | app_lucky_number | ANY | ANY | ANY | /lucky/number |
5. Opened in browser http://server.ip/symfony/lucky/number and get 404 Apache error.

Opened in browser http://server.ip/symfony/public/ and OK.

Opened in browser http://server.ip/symfony/public/index.php/lucky/number and OK.

Apache config in /etc/apache2/.../symfony.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/symfony/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/symfony/public>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        Require all granted
        #AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        #FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_rewrite is enable.

Anybody have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: try to uncomment FallbackResource or try with the optimized configuration describe in  symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Did you restart the Apache server after making changes?  In any event, just use the development server 'symfony server:start' and save yourself some time.

Comment: @AdrienChinour, done it already. Not helped.

Comment: @Cerad, tried this method, helped! Thanks. But really interesting how can work with Symfony 5 without inner server.

Comment: @Cerad, ofcourse restart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .htaccess in your project.

If you will use only apache configuration, you will be enabled FallbackResource index.php in your Directory

Following this configuration : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

**See section** : Use the following optimized configuration to disable .htaccess support and increase web server performance:

Comment: Already done it. Didn't work in both cases (with and without FallbackResource index.php).

Comment: Please share with me your configuration apache !!

Comment: how I can share? Or you mean copy paste